# How do I send and receive real-time signals `sigqueue()` in Python?

Tags: python, unix, signals, ipc, sigqueue

Python provides a `signals` module and `os.kill`; does it have a facility for `sigqueue()` (real-time signals with attached data)? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html)

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> c = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
>>> c.sigqueue
<_FuncPtr object at 0xb7dbd77c>
>>> c.sigqueue(100, 10, 0)
-1
>>>
```

You'll have to look up how to make a union in ctypes which I've never done before but I think is possible.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative, if no one has done it yet, would be to wrap the C library yourself - should be pretty quick and painless. [Look here](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ext/intro.html) for more details.