# Opening file in append mode and seeking to start

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, file-io

I've come across this strange behavior regarding opening a file in append mode and then attempting to seek to the start of the file.

The code should be self-explanatory: In the second open, I expect to be able to write a string to the beginning of the file and then have `f.tell()` return 5 (the number of bytes written at the beginning of the file).

The thing is that in Python 2.6.6 and 2.7.6 the final assert fires but, surprisingly, it works in Python 3.3.2.

```
# Create new file, write after the 100th byte.
f = open("test", "w+b")
f.seek(100, 0)
f.write(b"end")
assert f.tell() == 100 + len("end")
f.close()

# Open file for writing without overwriting, attempt to write at start of file
# of the file, but doesn't.
f = open("test", "a+b")
f.seek(0, 0)
f.write(b"start")
assert f.tell() == len("start")
f.close()
```

So I made a C program that does the equivalent. It actually behaves like the Python 2.x versions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *f = fopen("tt", "w+b");
  fseek(f, 100, 0);
  fwrite("x", 1, 1, f);
  fclose(f);

  f = fopen("tt", "a+b");
  fseek(f, 0, 0);
  fwrite("y", 1, 1, f);
  printf("%ld\n", ftell(f));
  fclose(f);

  return 0;
}
```

This prints `102`, and I consider this canonical (I've looked at `strace -eopen,close,lseek` outputs as well, but am none the smarter).

So my question is: What kind of embarrassingly basic knowledge do I not have?

And why does Python 3 behave differently?

By the way, I'm on Linux.

Comment: why not just use `rb+` if you want to write to the start?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You're right, but I just wanted to know why this specific situation didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The behaviour is one enforced by your *OS*.

The Python 2 `open()` call is actually opening files the same way your `C` code does, with a little more wrapping. Both ask the OS to open the file in a given mode. Your OS then *explicitly limits* where you can seek to; you are not *allowed* to seek to read or overwrite data that was there before you opened the file.

In Python 3 I/O has been overhauled and the new file handling code does not directly pass on the mode to the OS, allowing you to not be bound by that restriction. You can do the same in Python 2 by using the [`io.open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open).

The [`open()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) certainly warns you about certain OS behaviour where you cannot even use `seek` when using `a`:

> [...] `'a'` for appending (which on some Unix systems means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position).

On Linux the [`open()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) is explicit about just that behaviour:

> `O_APPEND`
>   The file is opened in append mode.  Before each `write(2)`, the
>                 file offset is positioned at the end of the file, as if with
>                 `lseek(2)`.

e.g. when trying to write, the file position is moved to the end of the file; you are only ever allowed to append.

I'm looking to find you a list of OSes that behave in that way; it looks like Microsoft Windows does something similar. The [.NET `FileMode` enumeration documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> `Append`
>   [...] Trying to seek to a position before the end of the file throws an `IOException` exception, and any attempt to read fails and throws a `NotSupportedException` exception.

In any case, if you want to both write to and read from a file (not just append), but not *truncate* the file when opening, use the `'r+'` mode. This opens the file for both reading and writing. You can append by seeking to the end, but at the same time you are free to seek to any point in the file.

Comment: Is this dependent on the specific file system I use?

Comment: @csl: no, it is an OS-level restriction, I think.

Comment: But why is this enforced? I was thinking that the first write may end up in a different block on disk, or something to that effect.

Comment: @csl: Either optimisation or protection; e.g. not having to cache the file data from before the `open()` call, and giving you a mode that prevents you from accidentally destroying data you didn't yourself append in this session.

Comment: You're edit was a very good explanation. I somehow expected this to be written down in K&R, but couldn't find any mention of this behaviour last time I had a look (I realize that this happens in the OS, but given the C interface, it could as well have been in the book). Thanks!

Comment: This also answer my question about whether the following is safe for a file that was opened in append mode: 1. Lock the file, 2. write to the file, 3. unlock the file. Indeed it is safe and is guaranteed to always append at the very end of the file, even if another process has previously append to the file and therefore modified what "at the end" means.