# named reentrant/recursive lock (RLock) in Python

Tags: python, synchronization, locking

The Python `multiprocessing` module has a class for reentrant/recursive locks:

```py
from multiprocessing import RLock

l = RLock()
l.acquire()
l.acquire()
l.release()
l.release()
```

This works great for processes that were forked from a common parent process and, hence, can share the same `RLock` object. However, for situations with **independent** processes (example: web server + cron job), one would need a **named** lock. Unfortunately, `RLock()` does not accept a name argument for the lock. Is there a solution that allows to do something like this?

```py
l = RLock('mylock')
l.acquire()
l.release()
```

Comment: did you read  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931342/system-wide-mutex-in-python-on-linux ?

Comment: I did. And while it brought some clarity, it did not answer the question. However, I found [this](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/) library. The `Semaphore` class might be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `oslo_concurrency.lockutils`.  It has a `lock` context manager and a `synchronized` decorator, both of which take a name and other handy interprocess-friendly parameters.