# How to integrate Blender with Novint Falcon

Tags: c++, blender

I'm looking for a clean solution or workflow to integrate the haptic device Novint Falcon with Blender Game Engine. Currently, I'm using UDP to transfer data from the C++ program to blender, but I think there is a much better way.

Comment: Although, your question is good, I think you might want to check (blender dedicated stack) this site and ask here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use [shared memory][1] between the C++ program and the Python script in Blender.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756813/simple-but-fast-ipc-method-for-a-python-and-c-application